# show the excel value as Red if the cellvalue is negative with comma for Polish and Czech Republic culture

Tags: .net, excel, aspose-cells

I am working on excel report generation using Aspose, my users are across various countries and they should see the report in their culture.
I am using aspose.net to generate the excel report, for Polish and Czech Republic culture they use ',' instead if '.' to represent decimal values. I need to highlight the negative values by showing background as grey and font color in red.
Only for these culture it doesn't apply red font.

```
          dataCell[exportUtil.constants.cell.numberFormat] = "#,##0,00;[Red]#,##0,00";
          dataCell[exportUtil.constants.cell.cellType] = "number"; 
          dataCell[exportUtil.constants.cell.colorBackground] = 14474460;
          dataCell[exportUtil.constants.cell.fontColor] = 255;
```

Below are the default custom excel format.

[image]

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following sample code for your reference. You may refer to the code segment and then write/update your own code accordingly for your needs.

e.g.,

**Sample code:**

```cs
//Instantiating a Workbook object
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
int index = sheet.ConditionalFormattings.Add();
FormatConditionCollection fcs = sheet.ConditionalFormattings[index];
//Sets the conditional format range.
CellArea ca = new CellArea();//A1:A11
ca.StartRow = 0;
ca.EndRow = 10;
ca.StartColumn = 0;
ca.EndColumn = 0;
fcs.AddArea(ca);
//Adds condition.
int conditionIndex = fcs.AddCondition(FormatConditionType.CellValue, OperatorType.LessThan, "0", null);
           
//Sets the formatting based on condition.
FormatCondition fc1 = fcs[conditionIndex];
fc1.Style.Custom = "#,##0,00;[Red]#,##0,00";
fc1.Style.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
fc1.Style.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
//Saving the Excel file
workbook.Save("g:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");
```

You may also post your queries or discuss further in the dedicated [forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.